# CSS is not showing on heroku django app

Tags: django, heroku

I'm having trouble showing my CSS/Static files on my django app I just deployed on Heroku. It doesn't show any debugging errors, so I don't know where to start.

Here is my code:

```
SETTINGS_DIR = os.path.dirname(__file__)
PROJECT_PATH = os.path.join(SETTINGS_DIR, os.pardir)
PROJECT_PATH = os.path.abspath(PROJECT_PATH)

STATIC_PATH = os.path.join(PROJECT_PATH, 'static')
STATIC_ROOT = 'staticfiles'
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    STATIC_PATH,
    )
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Used WhiteNoise to collectstaticfiles. Thanks for helping.

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django-assets for documentation.

Comment: I know I should avoid commenting just to say thanks, but geez, you've saved my life! I had been struggling with this for the past 4h thinking it was something in my React configs (I'm pretty new to React). Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 0):

Try setting an absolute path to your `STATIC_ROOT`. From [Django documentation: Settings](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/#std:setting-STATIC_ROOT):

> STATIC_ROOT
>
> The absolute path to the directory where `collectstatic` will collect static files for deployment.

Then make sure that you run `collectstatic`.

Last, I usually set `STATICFILES_DIRS` to `None` for deployment.